# Stuck in a reboot loop while updating to W10 (Lumia 625)

Tags: lumia, windows-10, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-625

After downloading the last W10 Preview, my phone is now stuck in a reboot loop... I do have the Nokia logo, then the Orange logo, then the gears appears for a few secs and after that the phone reboots and I get the Nokia logo, the Orange logo...etc. Progression bar is at 0% and don't want to rise.
This happen when the phone is charging. If it's not, it wont reboot after the wheels's crash. I'm able to do it manually, but the phone keeps crashing after the wheels appears.

I first thought that might be part of the update process but after waiting the whole night for the thing to get right I assume it's not...

I tried to press power button and low volume button togethers, no effect. The phone tries to boot but is still stuck at the same moment. I can't remove the battery since it's a 625 but i did so with my SD and SIM cards.

I'm running out of ideas so help would be greatly appreciated :)
BTW, sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Just found this: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/phone-got-stuck-during-upgrading-to-windows-10 I'll try what is suggested and I'll have you known if it worked.