# Update to Windows 10 Gone Wrong, Should I Try Again?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

Firstly, I am using a Nokia Lumia 625.

I recently attempted to update to W10 through the Insider Preview, but encountered an issue whereby the phone would continually show the Three logo>> Nokia Logo >> Update Cogs, before rebooting. This process would continue and is exactly as described in this thread:

1) [Stuck in a reboot loop while updating to W10 (Lumia 625)](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9878/stuck-in-a-reboot-loop-while-updating-to-w10-lumia-625)

After a number of days of annoyance and rebooting I finally used the Lumia Software Recovery Tool to roolback to 8.1. However, my issue now is that I am considering trying to update again because I want to which brings me to my questions ...

1) Should I update again, and how likely am I to face the problem again?
2) If I update again, how can I avoid the reboot loop?
3) If I decide not to update via the Insider Preview will I be able to get W10 on my Lumia 625 when it is officially released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same happened with me too. And yes, I tried again and Windows Phone 10 was fine this time.

Since you already have tried it, you may already know the steps. Downloading Windows Insider preview app from store. I would suggest you go for the slow releases, since at first I selected fast release download and had the same problem as you described above.

Here's a detailed article about it: [How to update your Windows Phone to Windows Phone 10 Preview](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/07/how-to-update-your-windows-phone-to-Windows-Phone-10-Preview.html)

I would also recommending [hard resetting your Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/07/how-to-hard-reset-your-windows-phone.html) once you have updated to Windows Phone 10 Technical Preview.

Comment: Excellent. I tried it again with the slow updates instead of the fast updates and it seems to have worked. I am not sure if it would have had the same problem if I'd chosen fast updates again, but slow updates definitely seems like the better option in my case.

Comment: Yes, actually I tried the fast updates twice earlier.. and failed. And slow update was fine. May be some issue with the build version that was at that time not compatible or having problems.