# Unable to turn on Lumia 520 while software updates running

Tags: update, lumia-520

Today i got software update notification in my phone Lumia 520. So i have given for update and updates got downloaded using my office wifi. And installing updates were started. I left my office and checked that it was updating still and couldn't turn on my mobile. It was nearly 5 to 6 hours went and still the updates are running and i couldn't switch on mobile. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Do you know which update it was? Have you signed up for the Insider Preview, for instance? Have you tried any of [the solutions](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9876/106) [where this has been](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/11153/106) a problem before?

Comment: If you're talking about whole software update, then it is normal, I updated my Lumia 520 few months back and it took a complete day as I had multiple software updates, So what I did was I kept it downloading the updates. Prior to that I made sure that Wi-Fi was working properly and kept my phone at charging during the process [I don't know whether, it should be kept at charging or not? But earlier also tried updating my phone but I couldn't, then my friend suggested this and it worked] and I also cleared a huge amount of memory space as whole software and / or OS update take much space and tim