# restarting problem

Tags: update, insider-preview

I have a Microsoft Lumia 520 and tried to install the Windows 10 preview. It was updating and showed the two gears moving. It was almost complete when it turned off, rebooted, and showed the gears again. Then it turned off and repeated the process. It keeps doing this over and over again. How do I fix this problem? Any answer is appreciated.
I used windows phone recovery tool but it does not recognize my phone as it is not started. plz help me with the issue.

Comment: Use the Lumia Software Recovery Tool to restore your phone to Windows Phone 8.1. Also, I don't recommend the current version of Windows 10 for phones for the Lumia 520 as it's very sluggish.

Comment: Possible duplicate; http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9816/106