# The update of Nokia Lumia 630 is very slow

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-630

By mistake, I began the update of my phone and now it's very  slow; I want to stop the update.

I rebooted the phone but it still shows the update process.

Please, suggest me some idea to stop the update process.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/phone-got-stuck-during-upgrading-to-windows-10

Comment: Did you perform an update to a next version of Windows Phone 8.1 or you tried to install the Insider Preview?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using Windows 10 mobile update right now, so for you to go back, you should use the Nokia Recovery Tool.

You can download the tool in your PC from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987).

Connect your phone and it will revert the update.

Be aware that all your phone data will be erased, so make a backup first.