# Lumia 820 doesn't pass Nokia logo and Settings animation

Tags: 8.1, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-820

I previously had Windows Phone 8.1 and tries to install Windows Phone 10 and while its installing (showing the Settings animation) I plugged the phone to a Windows 7 PC and it tried to Install a driver called "Nokia BOOTMGR" and I cancelled it. After that, the behavior is 
1) Showing Nokia logo
2) Showing Settings animation
3) Restarting automatically
4) Go to step 1 and loop through above steps

so I am unable to boot the phone. How to resolve this?
I tried soft-resetting it does not help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9816/106