# Phone Fails to Boot After Windows 10 Update

Tags: update, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-1020

After downloading the update, deployed from server, the device rebooted and got stuck in Windows Boot Manager. It says:

> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. Please insert installation disk... LOL
>
> File:\EFT\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
> Station: 0x000034
> Info: The Boot configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors

Already tried the common hard reset sequences; no results.
Device remains restarting on the Lumia screen followed by Windows Boot Manager message

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9816/106 (specifically, try http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9876/106)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use [Windows Device Recovery Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987)?

I have the same problem before. I tried to use Windows Phone Recovery Tools to rollback to WP8.1 Denim and re-upgrade it to Windows 10 Mobile. It works like charm :D