# Iumia 525 battery power off during upgrading.

Tags: update

My phone power off during updating because of battery low, than i put my phone on charging and start it again by pressing power button but phone restart again and again and show upgrading sign and does not show any further sign ,so what should i do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9816/106