# Lumia 620 stuck while updating Windows 10

Tags: update, insider-preview, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-620

My Lumia 620 is running Windows 10, and last night it said updates were available. I started the update, then suddenly the phone turned off, and it only shows the NOKIA logo. It's been this way for 15 hours already. What should I do?

Comment: Related: [Phone got stuck during upgrading to Windows 10](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/phone-got-stuck-during-upgrading-to-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

Try following steps in this order:

- [soft reset](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/nokia/nokia-lumia-620/#softreset)
- [hard reset](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/nokia/nokia-lumia-620/)
- device reset using the [Windows Devices Recovery Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987)

Answer (score 1):

Revert back to windows phone 8.1 using [Device recovery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987) and than update again. This happens while phone is updating and it turn off due to battery. Make sure battery is full when you update your phone