# Is downloading updates resumable?

Tags: insider-preview

I was updating my Lumia via Insider app. And now the download is stuck at 59%. If I restart my phone, will the download resume* from 59% the next time I connect to Wi-Fi? Or will it discard the 59% already downloaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9816/106 If not, feel free to [edit your question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/posts/12315/edit) to be specific

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the Wi-Fi connection and then connect again ( found out myself). The download will resume fine... 69% now.