# Windows mobile 10 update failed during install impossible to recover

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update

I have a big problem with my lumia 830 after the update this night the install start and fail after a short time with a kind smiley :-(.

So i tried to recover my phone with the Windows Device Recovery Tool, but once I connect my phone to my PC, the phone always try to install the update and restart after he failed.
The tool connect to the phone for a short lapse of time so I successfully download the system img but I cannot install it because the phone doesn't hold the connection.

EDIT-------

I tried a hardreset but it doesn't work, after pressing the power button and then hold the volume down button the phone restart after 5secondes (and so on) and never displaythe exclamation(!).

Any idea how i can recover my phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/phone-got-stuck-during-upgrading-to-windows-10?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can try following options

**Option1**

If the connection is lost every time, you can try to add your phone manually to the Windows Device Recovery Tool (WDRT). Todo so click "My device has not been detected" and choose your phone.

[image]

After adding your phone, you have to reset/restart your phone. For this simply Press and hold the Power and Volume down keys simultaneously. Release the keys when your phone vibrates. Now you should be able to install the firmware.

**Option2**

Alternatively you can bring your phone into recovery mode. For the recovery mode first disconnect the phone. Turn the Phone off (Long press the power button).
Now press and hole the volume down key and connect the charger.
While there's the Exklamation mark, try to start the installation from WDRT

**Option3**
Hardreset by Phone keys

1. Turn the Phone Off
2. Press and hold the Volume down button, briefly press the Power button. Keep the volume down button held until an Exclamation (!) logo appears (all fingers released)
3. Now press in sequence: the Volume Up key (and release)
4. next press the Volume Down key (and release)
5. now press the Power key (and release)
6. Lastly press the Volume Down key (and release)

(Information from http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Nokia-Lumia-830.how_to_perform_a_hard_reset_when_my_nokia_lumia)

**EDIT-2016-07-31:** Option3 Updated

Comment: I tried the 2 first option I will try the hard reset

Comment: By trying the hard reset when I click on the volume down button the phone goes off vibrate and goes off and again, there never is a exclamation logo :(.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the phone with PC (PC on Windows OS). Open Windows Device Recovery Tool. Wait for some time. Probably it will say no device found or some things like this. Click on my device was not detected. Now wait till it shows some instructions on screen to restart the device boot loader environment. Probably it will say to press some key combinations (volume keys and power keys of your phone) after switching off your device. When your device started in boot loader environment, the Windows Device Recovery Tool will automatically detect your device and will start installation of device software (factory image) if it was already downloaded.

I faced similar problem with my Lumia 730 when I installed a preview build of Windows 10 on my device. It's USB connection was stopped working (It was not connecting with PC via USB connection). Then method described above helped me.

Comment: Doesn't work too, my phone is detected by the recovery tool but after 10secondes the phone continue the execution and try to install the update, it fails and stops (and the connection to the recovery tool is lost)

Answer (score -1):

Connect the phone with PC (PC on Windows OS). Open Windows Device Recovery Tool. Wait for some time. Probably it will say no device found or some things like this. Click on my device was not detected.

Comment: This appears to be just a partial copy of Amandeep's answer, and doesn't appear to ad anything else. Did you intend to add more detail?