# Lumia Icon froze when updated Windows 10

Tags: update

I have a Lumia Icon phone and had just updated my computer and was notified I could update my phone as well.  It has froze on the spinning gear and wont do anything.  What do I do?

Comment: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/phone-got-stuck-during-upgrading-to-windows-10